# How to get datetime value as a result for a paticular category in all columns of a csv in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a csv file containing values of user's social media activity for 20 days I want to get the details of the user activity on Day 1 Here is the example of the entries in the csv

```
DateTime                  Instagram  Facebook   Twitter
(2020,09,01,10,00,00)        Y          N         Y
(2020,09,01,10,01,00)        N          Y         Y
(2020,09,01,10,02,00)        N          Y         N
(2020,09,01,10,03,00)        N          Y         N
(2020,09,01,10,04,00)        Y          N         Y
(2020,09,01,11,00,00)        Y          N         N
(2020,09,02,10,00,00)        N          Y         Y
(2020,09,02,10,00,00)        Y          N         N
(2020,09,02,10,00,00)        N          N         N
(2020,09,03,10,00,00)        Y          Y         Y
```

Y stands for user was active, N stands for user was inactive
I want to display active stats of all apps  for Day 1 that is `2020-09-01`(1st September 2020).

so I want the result to look like this(only datetime values of when the user was active(Y) on that app)

```
{'Instagram':[(2020,09,01,10,00,00),(2020,09,01,10,04,00),(2020,09,01,11,00,00)],
 'Facebook':[(2020,09,01,10,01,00), (2020,09,01,10,02,00), (2020,09,01,10,03,00)],
 'Twitter':[(2020,09,01,10,00,00), (2020,09,01,10,01,00), (2020,09,01,10,04,00)]}
```

I wrote a piece of code but then it didn't provide me the desired result

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], format='(%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S)')

for idx, d in df.groupby(df['DateTime'].dt.date):
    print(d.drop('DateTime', axis=1).to_dict('list'))

This was the result I got
    
{'Instagram': ['Y', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'Y'], 'Facebook': ['N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'N'], 'Twitter': ['Y', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'N']}
{'Instagram': ['N', 'Y', 'N'], 'Facebook': ['Y', 'N', 'N'], 'Twitter': ['Y', 'N', 'N']}
{'Instagram': ['Y'], 'Facebook': ['Y'], 'Twitter': ['Y']}
```

The DateTime column consists of values of datetime objects format, I converted it into pandas datetime format

Comment: Output is only for one date, first day?

Comment: Yes, the first day only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert values to new column, filter first date by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), then unpivot by [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and aggreagate `list`:

```
df['d'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], format='(%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S)')

day1 = df['d'].dt.date[0]
df = df[df['d'].dt.date.eq(day1)] 

df = df.melt(['DateTime','d']) 
df = df[df['value'].eq('Y')] 


d = df.groupby('variable')['DateTime'].agg(list).to_dict()
print (d)
{'Facebook': ['(2020,09,01,10,01,00)', '(2020,09,01,10,02,00)', '(2020,09,01,10,03,00)'], 
 'Instagram': ['(2020,09,01,10,00,00)', '(2020,09,01,10,04,00)', '(2020,09,01,11,00,00)'], 
 'Twitter': ['(2020,09,01,10,00,00)', '(2020,09,01,10,01,00)', '(2020,09,01,10,04,00)']}
```

If need output for each `datetime` in nested dictionaries:

```
df['d'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], format='(%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S)')

df = df.melt(['DateTime','d']) 
df = df[df['value'].eq('Y')] 

s = df.groupby([df['d'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), 'variable'])['DateTime'].agg(list)
print (s)

d1 = {level: s.xs(level).to_dict() for level in s.index.levels[0]}
print (d1)
{'2020-09-01': {'Facebook': ['(2020,09,01,10,01,00)', '(2020,09,01,10,02,00)', '(2020,09,01,10,03,00)'], 
                'Instagram': ['(2020,09,01,10,00,00)', '(2020,09,01,10,04,00)', '(2020,09,01,11,00,00)'],
                'Twitter': ['(2020,09,01,10,00,00)', '(2020,09,01,10,01,00)', '(2020,09,01,10,04,00)']},
 '2020-09-02': {'Facebook': ['(2020,09,02,10,00,00)'], 
                'Instagram': ['(2020,09,02,10,00,00)'], 
                'Twitter': ['(2020,09,02,10,00,00)']}, 
 '2020-09-03': {'Facebook': ['(2020,09,03,10,00,00)'], 
                'Instagram': ['(2020,09,03,10,00,00)'], 
                'Twitter': ['(2020,09,03,10,00,00)']}}

print (d1['2020-09-01'])
{'Facebook': ['(2020,09,01,10,01,00)', '(2020,09,01,10,02,00)', '(2020,09,01,10,03,00)'], 
 'Instagram': ['(2020,09,01,10,00,00)', '(2020,09,01,10,04,00)', '(2020,09,01,11,00,00)'],
 'Twitter': ['(2020,09,01,10,00,00)', '(2020,09,01,10,01,00)', '(2020,09,01,10,04,00)']}

print (d1['2020-09-02'])
{'Facebook': ['(2020,09,02,10,00,00)'], 'Instagram': ['(2020,09,02,10,00,00)'], 'Twitter': ['(2020,09,02,10,00,00)']}
```

Comment: @GlenVeigas - Thanks, glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it suits you! :)

Comment: when I run the first solution on Colab\Jupyter it works perfectly fine, but when I run it on my terminal via a .py file I get this error: TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable

Comment: The error is pointed towards ```d = df.groupby('variable')['DateTime'].agg(list).to_dict()```

Comment: @GlenVeigas - What is `print (type(df.loc[0, 'DateTime']))` before my solution in data, which fail?

Comment: It is ```<class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>```

Comment: @GlenVeigas - and `print (type(df.loc[0, 'variable']))` before `d = df.groupby('variable')['DateTime'].agg(list).to_dict()` ?

Comment: This is what I get ```KeyError: 'the label [0] is not in the [index]'```

Comment: @GlenVeigas - and `print (type(df.loc[df.index[0], 'variable']))` ?

Comment: type of class string ```<class 'str'>```

Comment: @GlenVeigas - It is OK, and `print (type(df.loc[df.index[0], 'DateTime']))` before `d = df.groupby('variable')['DateTime'].agg(list).to_dict()` ? I guess it is not `<class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>`

Comment: It is ```<class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>```

Comment: @GlenVeigas - It is weird, it should working nice. Not idea :(

Answer (score 0):

use readline to read the file.csv line by line of. Then u should gather the datetime of Instagram (In the case of "Y", so use if) in a list. Do the same for Facebook and Twitter.

So, This is the overall method:

```
Instagram=[] #make an empty list
for row in file.readlines():  #read line by line of your file
    row2=row.split(';')  #split elements and make a list with name row2
    if str(row2[1])=="Y": Instagram.append(row2[0]) # add date time to instagram list
    #do the same for facebook and twitter
print(Instagram)
```